# How do I install or use NPM in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following error when I try to run my node.js project:

```
ENV@ENV-L7490:/mnt/c/Users/ENV/source/Project$ npm i
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: 
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5: 
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
ENV@ENV-L7490:/mnt/c/Users/ENV/source/Project$ npm init
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: 
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5: 
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
ENV@ENV-L7490:/mnt/c/Users/ENV/source/Project$
```

Any idea what this means and how to resolve. I'm unable to actually run the project with `npm start`, until I run my `npm i` or `npm init`, which is why I want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: please reinstall your node (npm) and try again that will work

Comment: Have you followed the installation guide? https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm/

Comment: Thanks for the response! In my git bash terminal, I'm able to run the program in the meantime. But after a re-install, it seemed to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use nvm instead, its convenient and personally I did not face above issue in WSL setup which following this:
https://gist.github.com/noygal/6b7b1796a92d70e24e35f94b53722219